# How do I make it so that the method onMapReady only happens activates when I click the button

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

Can anyone help me. How do I make it so that my onMapReady method only happen when I click my button. So how do I make it an onlick method.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    LatLng Maharashtra = new LatLng(19.169257, 73.341601);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Maharashtra).title("Maharashtra").snippet("Population: 210312321").infoWindowAnchor(0.8f, 0.8f).draggable(true).zIndex(1));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Maharashtra));
}
```

}
I want to make this an onclick method but i am not sure how
do i just make another method and call this method and if so how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this solution :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap; 
}
```

Create new method for clicking action

```
public void whenClick (){
    LatLng Maharashtra = new LatLng(19.169257, 73.341601);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Maharashtra).title("Maharashtra").snippet("Population: 210312321").infoWindowAnchor(0.8f, 0.8f).draggable(true).zIndex(1));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Maharashtra));
}
```

You can also clear the map like that :

```
public void clear (){
  map.clear()
}
```

Comment: Should whenClick() be whenClick(View v)?

Comment: Yes if you use the actions biding